# Change "eg" to "e.g." on https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, salary-calculator, spelling

On the https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary page, in the drop down you can see "eg" three times, and outside the drop down there is "e.g." "eg" should be corrected to "e.g." since the page needs to be consistent

[image]

Comment: My research indicates that "e.g" is short for the Latin _exempli gratia_, and requires the periods.  "eg" is not a word.  So should a spelling correction be a "feature-request" or a "bug"?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I think your right, I changed it

Comment: This isn't a bug, this is just a typo

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson The tag description is broad enough to also match a typo.

Comment: While you're at it, you might also want to add a comma afterwards, i.e., "Graduate degree (e.g., MA, MS)", if you want it to be formally correct and in accordance with most style guides.

Comment: Or it could be "corrected" to *for example*, which is a lot more accessible to non-native speakers. "e.g." and "i.e." are overused as it is. It doesn't look like the abbrevs. are necessary to save room there.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson it's a bug. You probably mean it's not a *functional bug* as in, some operation being incorrect, and it also might be *minor*, as opposed to something that has large consequences, but it's still a problem.

Comment: It's also usually traditional to write "PhD", not "Ph.D", though the latter is at least partially correct and is ostensibly used in that far-away land with two countries on it known as North America (why not "Ph.D." though? why not "B.A."?)

Comment: The abbreviations should read `Ph.D.` or `PhD` but not `Ph.D` (ditto for the others)

Comment: The _Chicago manual of style_ recommends omitting periods unless required for tradition or consistency (BA, BS, MA, MS, PhD), but the _Associated Press Stylebook_ prefers retaining the periods (B.A., B.S., M.A., M.S., Ph.D.).

Comment: I propose we use the term "egprex" instead.  (Please don't hate me, Shog.)

Comment: @BJMyers That's not how it works. You have to find some obscure R library that uses the term first.

Comment: I just wrote one ... but it is so obscure you will never find it :-)

Comment: Isn't the simple fix to just add an extra G, so it becomes egg. That looks like a fine word to me.

Comment: @Luuklag The best laid plans, and all that...

Comment: It should also be bachelor's.

Comment: Egad! missing punctuation!

Comment: Where's the freehand circle?

Comment: In "Less than a Bachelor's", ["Lesser" would be more correct](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/24749/142476)? "Half a Bachelor's" < "A Bachelor's" but a City and Guilds is a lesser degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this was fixed back in September 2019, but we never [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) this request.